# no_db_file error in ecoinpool

Tags: mining-pools, development, miner-configuration

I have successfully installed ecoinpool and couchdb on my server and both are working great just the problem is that when i try to create a worker i get the following error "Database information could not be retrieved: no_db_file" then i get a list of errors like this "An error occurred accessing the view: no_db_file" can anyone please tell me what's wrong its like out of the world to me, my config file is like this

```
% This is an example configuration file. Lists are denoted with [...] and tuples
% are denoted with {...}. Together they form a nested structure of names and
% parameters. If you make changes and add or remove options, make sure not to
% have a comma before a closing bracket or curly brace.

[
% SASL is Erlang's internal error and crash logger; it also logs starting
% and stopping of certain processes. I set it to "error" here so it won't
% pollute stdout/stderr.
{sasl, [
    {errlog_type, error}
]},

% This is ecoinpool's main configuration. The CouchDB connection is
% configured here.
{ecoinpool, [
    % The following commented lines are default settings.
    {db_host, "127.0.0.1"},
    %{db_port, 5984},
    %{db_prefix, ""},

    % The next line should be changed, depending on your CouchDB
    % authentication settings: username password
    {db_options, [{basic_auth, {"admin", "password"}}]},

    % Here you can change ecoinpool's HTTP service port, currently used to
    % serve global RPC functions used by the frontend.
    %{service_port, 8080},

    % The last line in this section contains your blowfish secret key, share
    % this among your servers and don't tell it to anyone else. Minimum key
    % length is 4 bytes, maximum is 56 bytes.
    % If you have pwgen (a password generator), try "pwgen -s 56 1" to get
    % 56 random characters.
    {blowfish_secret, "a1a2a3a4a5"}
]},

% This is the ebitcoin configuration. ebitcoin forms a separate application,
% thus it doesn't share ecoinpool's database settings. If you use the same
% CouchDB server and authentication, copy it from above.
{ebitcoin, [
    % You can also disable ebitcoin altogether by uncommenting the following
    % line. Note that you will fall back to the polling system then.
    %{enabled, false},

    {db_host, "127.0.0.1"},
    %{db_port, 5984},
    %{db_prefix, ""},
    {db_options, [{basic_auth, {"admin", "password"}}]}
]},

% The third separate application (it also has to be started separately) is
% the MySQL Replicator. It is used to bridge legacy MySQL worker tables to
% CouchDB and also stores copies of the shares into a MySQL table.
{ecoinpool_mysql_replicator, [
    % Again, commented lines are default settings.
    {couchdb_host, "127.0.0.1"},
    %{couchdb_port, 5984},
    %{couchdb_prefix, ""},
    {couchdb_options, [{basic_auth, {"admin", "password"}}]},
    {couchdb_database, "ecoinpool"},

    {mysql_host, "127.0.0.1"},
    %{mysql_port, 3306},
    %{mysql_prefix, ""},
    {mysql_options, [{auth, {"mysqladmin", "mysqlpass"}}]},
    %{mysql_database, "ecoinpool"},

    % This is a setting that certainly has to be changed. Configure one or
    % more worker table replicators here (if you have multiple sub-pools).
    % Please only connect one sub-pool to one table or things get jammed up.
    {replicator_configs, [
        % Format: {<ecoinpool sub-pool ID>, <MySQL worker table>, <MySQL sync interval in seconds, 1 or more>}
        {"e66e45a18eff533e9e690c7f1d005279", "pool_worker", 15}
    ]},

    % Next is your blowfish secret key. Copy it from above.
    {blowfish_secret, "Replace me!"},

    % And the last one, also to be likely changed, is the shares deployer
    % configuration. There are two possible formats here, one with and one
    % without using merged mining. The config ID is used as basename for
    % saving the deployment state file and for the "source" column.
    {share_deployer_configs, [
        % Non-MM Format: {<config ID string>, <pool name>, <MySQL shares table>, <MySQL write interval in seconds, 0 allowed>}
        {"ltc_test_shares", "ltc-test", "shares", 60},
        % MM Format: {<config ID string>, <main pool name>, <aux pool name>, <MySQL shares table>, <MySQL write interval in seconds, 0 allowed>}
        {"btc_nmc_test_shares", "btc-test", "nmc-test", "shares", 60}
    ]}
]}
].
```